# Effect of parameter $unused in method apcu_store

Tags: php, apc, apcu

I'm trying to use APCu on PHP7. I checked the documentation for method [apcu_store](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-store.php):

`apcu_store ( array $values [, mixed $unused = NULL [, int $ttl = 0 ]] ) : array`

One of the parameters is `mixed $unused = NULL`.
There is no description of the purpose of this parameter. Does anyone know its effect?

Comment: Well as long as they are officially calling it `$unused` in the documentation, it would assume it is exactly that - **un-used**, as in has no meaning whatsoever …

Comment: Looks to me as if was simply done in order to keep the function signature the same. In the first version shown in the manual, a single key and a single value are passed as the first two parameters; the second version takes an array that contains multiple key-value pairs for the first one, making the second parameter superfluous in that situation.

Comment: @04FS Oh, it was simple now that I was taught. Anyway, it was good that the question was solved. Thank you.